# Whats the difference between these three ways of creating a new List<string> in C#?

Tags: c#

Whats the difference between these three ways of creating a new `List<string>` in C#?

```
A = new List<string>();
B = new List<string> { };
C = new List<string>() { };
```

Comment: () inits the variable
{} puts data in the variable

Im not sure B would compile? But A = C ;)

Comment: Maybe () inits the variable, but what difference it make, still Count=0

Comment: All compiles, in fact, I just found some of my early codes all like B, feel weird then I come here ask this question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are equivalent, all three create an empty `List<string>`.

1. is a simple, parameterless constructor
2. uses the collection initialization syntax, where you are allowed to omit the braces of the constructor if the class provides a parameterless constructor
3. the same as 2., just providing the optional constructor braces.

The collection initialization syntax allows you to provide data while constructing the object,

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
```

gets expanded to

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("one");
list.Add("two");
list.Add("three");
```

by the compiler.

Comment: Object initialization syntax: `new Foo(){Bar="hello", Count=2};` Collection initialization syntax: `new List<string>(){"one","two"};` - so "collection initialization syntax" is the correct term in your usage.

Answer (score 8):

There is no difference because you are not initializing anything inside the list at the time of declaring it.

If you were to add some strings at declaration-time, you would need to go with the second or third choice:

```
var B = new List<string> { "some", "strings" };
var C = new List<string>() { "some", "strings" };
```

The third option would only be necessary if you were to pass a value into the `List<of T>` constructor:

```
var C = new List<string>(5) { "some", "strings" };
```

or

```
var C = new List<string>(5); // empty list but capacity initialized with 5.
```

There are more constructors available for the `List<of T>` class as well (e.g. passing an existing collection or IEnumerable into the List constructor). See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0cyc8ex.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 4):

Those are all identical. There's no difference in the end result, just in the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, all three statements do the same: they create an empty string list. Statement B and C can assign some initial data to the list, e.g.

```
ingredients = new List<string> { "Milk", "Sugar", "Flour" };
```

The `()` as in statement C can omitted then.

Answer (score 1):

`{}` is used for collection\object initilizer.
If it remains blank it doesn't do a thing.

So all those lines produces the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you gave to us, the result will be the same.

In terms of performance you will not find any problem using any of that options for initializing a empty list, because the IL generated will one contain the ctor(), as you can see using the IL DASM.

If you want to initialize the list with some information, you can go for the option 2 or 3.

```
List<string> b = new List<string> { "abc", "abc" };
List<string> c = new List<string>() { "abc", "abc"};
```

In terms of performance is also the same, the IL generated will be exactly the same, containing the *ctor()* and two *Add* for both.

But you should use the best one to read. To avoid any problem reading the code for you colleagues, I would go for

```
 List<string> a = new List<string>();
```

But that is a question of personal opinion.

Comment: I was use new List<string> {}, more like an object for me. But now I start to use new List<string>() {}, more clear on what I am doing.