# Adding items to List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was going a through a MVC tutorial when I bump into this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    dynamic genres = new List<Genre> {
        new Genre { Name = "Disco" },
        new Genre { Name = "Jazz" },
        new Genre { Name = "Rock" }
    };
    return View(genres);
}
```

What is the difference if I use `Genre.Add("Disco");`... instead. Thanks.

Comment: or May be `Add` is a static method on Genre which creates its own object specified by the string `Name`. unless we see Genre class, nothing can be said :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>I presume you mean the difference between that and `genres.Add` (the `List<T>.Add` method) as `Genre.Add` might be a static method on `Genre` or an instance method on a `Genre` variable, neither of which have been posted.</sub>

There is no *behavioural* difference in the final code, it is only a visual difference.

Not sure why you are using `dynamic` (perhaps you are looking for `var`?), but the difference is that this is called [collection initialization syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx), basically sugar over calling `.Add` manually:

```
var genres = new List<Genre> {
    new Genre { Name = "Disco" },
    new Genre { Name = "Jazz" },
    new Genre { Name = "Rock" }
};
```

Is equivalent to:

```
var genres = new List<Genre>();
genres.Add(new Genre { Name = "Disco" });
genres.Add(new Genre { Name = "Jazz" });
genres.Add(new Genre { Name = "Rock" });
```

The compiler outputs the `.Add` for you in your case.

[Whats the difference between these three ways of creating a new List<string> in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695528/whats-the-difference-between-these-three-ways-of-creating-a-new-liststring-in)

Also in your example, you are seeing the object initializer syntax with:

```
new Genre { Name = "Disco" }
```

Which equates to:

```
var g = new Genre();
g.Name = "Disco";
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear why you're using `dynamic` here to start with, to be honest. But if you used

```
List<Genre> genres = new List<Genre>();
genres.Add(new Genre { Name = "Disco" });
genres.Add(new Genre { Name = "Jazz" });
genres.Add(new Genre { Name = "Rock" });
```

it would have the same effect.

Note that it's `genres.Add`, not `Genre.Add`.

I'd also suggest that if you create a Genre constructor taking the name, it will make the code simpler - or if you want to still make the name part explicit, you could create a `Genre.FromName` static method.

Answer (score 1):

In compiled terms none. It's actually syntax sugar for

```
dynamic genres = new List<Genre();
genres.Add(new Genre...
```

This is what I assume you meant, since `Genre.Add(string)` isn't described.

Comment: how are u so sure it is not described? :)